# problem with solving a simple third order differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I just wrote a simple line of code to solve a third-order differential equation:

```
DSolve[{y'''[x] + 4*y[x]==0, y[0]==1, y'[0]==2, y''[0]==0}, y[x], x]
```

Then Mathematica said:
[image]

Could you please tell me what I did wrong?
Thanks

Comment: My guess is it cached something from an incorrect syntax, so restart your kernel or clear everything because I copied and pasted your stuff and it worked.

Comment: Execute this: ``ClearAll["`"]; Remove["`*"];`` and next: `DSolve`

Comment: @Ma That won't work, it's `Derivative` that's polluted.